# How to give access of Response sheet linked with Google Form to only those who filled form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Let's say I'm collecting Name and Email (using Collect Emails setting), I wish to allow view-access to the Google Sheets Response Sheet linked to that form with only those who put their email id. Assume every email-id entered will be of Gmail.
How can I do it without manually putting emails in share option.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. P.S. There is not an automatic built-in feature that does this, you might do it manually, using Google Apps Script, the Google Sheets API, an add-on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution would be to **File > Share** the spreadsheet as `anyone with link can view`. If you do not publish the link address anywhere, it will not be easily discoverable.

You can then use one of the many mail merge add-ons to send an automatic response email to people who submit a form and include their email address. The email message would include the link to the spreadsheet, enabling those responders to open it and see all the responses. Others would not know the link address, and would therefore not have access.

To find a suitable mail merge add-on, choose **Add-ons > Get add-ons** and search for `mail merge`.